# Spring Boot Facebook Authentication

Tags: java, facebook, spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to integrate logging into facebook with spring security. I am following this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

My Application.java:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "app.configuration"})
    @EnableOAuth2Sso
    public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
        }
}
```

My SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

I also create application.yml file that looks exactly the same as in tutorial.

As I read in tutorial now when I enter localhost:8080/login I should be redirected to facebook login page but instead I am getting 404 not found from spring boot server. What steps I missed or what am I missing in my configuration to get this work?